# Trying to set up Spyder (Anaconda 3) with Python 3.11 Getting Error

Tags: python, odbc, spyder, pyodbc, progress

I am trying to import pyodbc for a long script that I know works. I just got a new PC and am setting things back up.

"('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  193:  (Progress OpenEdge 11.1 Driver, C:\Progress\OpenEdge\pgoe26.dll). (160) (SQLDriverConnect); [IM003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)')"

Any ideas on what I could try? Please let me know if there is anything else that could help troubleshoot.

I have set up the Progress Open Edge Driver, and set up the ODBC 32 bit data source. However, I keep getting this error when trying to run the script. I get the same error when I try to set up the ODBC 64 bit data source. I have also added the paths of python and site packages.

I am expecting the script to run as it did on my previous PC. Script still runs to this day, still have old PC running so can check things out if need be.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: error shows `[ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)'` so it seems problem only with ODBC driver settings and it has nothing to do with `Spyder`. If it is new computer then it may need different settings then old computer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.